# Vue filter items list with array

Tags: vue.js

I have an array of items that I filter like this.

```js
return this.items.filter((item) => {
    return !this.requestType || (item.requestsubtypeid === this.requestType && item.status === this.status);
})
```

This works perfectly, when `this.requestType` is only a number. But now it can be an array, so my question is, how can I filter when it is an array?
Should I use a for loop or is there a better was for that?

Answer (score 0):

If requestType is always an array you can use following:

```js
return this.items.filter((item) => {
    return !this.requestType || (this.requestType.includes(item.requestsubtypeid) && item.status === this.status);
})
```